# Repeating an SQL code for All (i, i+1) combinations

Tags: db2

I have this table on football players ("players"):

```
 year  name var1 year2
 2000 Name 5    0    NA
 2000 Name 1    0  2002
 2000 Name 3    1  2004
 2000 Name 2    1    NA
 2000 Name 4    0    NA
 2001 Name 4    1    NA
 2001 Name 2    1  2002
 2001 Name 1    0    NA
 2001 Name 3    1    NA
 2001 Name 5    1    NA
 2002 Name 5    0  2001
 2002 Name 3    1    NA
 2002 Name 1    0    NA
 2002 Name 4    0  2004
 2002 Name 2    1  2003
 2003 Name 1    1    NA
 2003 Name 5    0  2004
 2003 Name 3    0    NA
 2003 Name 2    0  2000
 2003 Name 4    0    NA
 2004 Name 2    0    NA
 2004 Name 1    0    NA
 2004 Name 4    0  2004
 2004 Name 5    0    NA
 2004 Name 3    1    NA
```

Here is what I am trying to do: Take all names in the year=2000 where var1=1

- In 2000, how many names where var1=1
- In 2001, how many of these names still have var1=1 and year2 not null?
- In 2001, how many of these names have var1 !=1 and year2 not null?
- In 2001, how many of these are simply not there? (nf)
- In 2001, how many of these names have year2 is null?

Here is what I did:

```
WITH names_2000 AS (
  SELECT name
  FROM players
  WHERE year = 2000 AND var1 = 1
),

names_2001 AS (
  SELECT name, var1, year2
  FROM players
  WHERE year = 2001
)

SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM names_2000) AS count_names_2000_var1,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN n1.var1 = 1 AND n1.year2 IS NOT NULL THEN n1.name END) AS count_names_2001_var1_year2_not_null,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN n1.var1 != 1 AND n1.year2 IS NOT NULL THEN n1.name END) AS count_names_2001_var_not_1_year2_not_null,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN n1.name IS NULL THEN n0.name END) AS count_names_not_in_2001,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN n1.year2 IS NULL THEN n1.name END) AS count_names_2001_year2_null
FROM names_2000 n0
LEFT JOIN names_2001 n1 ON n0.name = n1.name;
```

Can someone please help me figure out how to do this for all (year = year, year = year+1) combinations? I wrote a python script to loop this code for all (year = year, year = year+1) combinations, but is it possible to do it directly in SQL?

Comment: It would depend on your table definition for `year`. is it an integer? If so, you should be able to do `WHERE n0.year = n1.year + 1`. or you might need to use `YEAR(year)` or `CAST year TO INTEGER` first

Comment: I meant `n0.year + 1 = n1.year`